# Using Scala, how does one differentiate XML elements having elements as children, or having text?

Tags: xml, parsing, scala

I'm parsing some xml, and given a particular node, I'm trying to figure out which one of these it is:

- An element with nested elements

  <theElement><nestedElement>foobar</nestedElement></theElement>
- An element with text/data in it

  <theElement>foobar</theElement>

I've tried checking the length of Node.text, but Node.text returns "foobar" for *theElement* in both of the above examples.

My code is recursing down through an XML structure, and at each point needs to know if its reached some text/data, or if there are more elements below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def textChildren(xml: Node) = xml match {
  case Elem(prefix, label, attribs, scope, Text(text)) => println("Only text children: "+text)
  case _ => println("Other kinds of children")
}

scala> textChildren(<a>XML example</a>)
Only text children: XML example

scala> textChildren(<a><nested>XML example</nested></a>)
Other kinds of children

scala> textChildren(<a>Text with <nested>XML</nested> example</a>)
Other kinds of children
```

Comment: thx, that works well.  Could you also do xml.Child match { case Text(text) => case _ => }?

Comment: The method returns a `Seq[Node]`, so you'll probably need to write `case Seq(Text(text)) =>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the solution, tried it out in repl:

```
scala> val xml1 = <theElement><nestedElement>foobar</nestedElement></theElement>
xml1: scala.xml.Elem = <theElement><nestedElement>foobar</nestedElement></theElement>

scala> val xml2 = <theElement>foobar</theElement>
xml2: scala.xml.Elem = <theElement>foobar</theElement>

scala> xml1.child.first.label
res0: String = nestedElement

scala> xml2.child.first.label
res1: String = #PCDATA
```

e.g.

```
if ( node.child.first.label == "#PCDATA" ) {
  // Its got data in it
} else {
  // Its got elements below it
}
```